# calling Java from Oracle 11g without using static methods

Tags: java, oracle, methods, oracle11g, member

I apologize.  Reading it again did seem kinda silly.  There are really 2 questions.
Here is the code.  I am trying to call a Java class from an Oracle 11g stored function, but am getting a 00932 error saying that the IN parameter in 1st position is not consistent.  I have simplified it quite a bit to try and illustrate the issue.

The 2nd part was I did get this working as long as the Java function was declared static, but I wasn't sure if that approach was ok since there will be up to 1000 users hitting the function at the same time and there is no instance of the object per user.  Not sure how oracle handles the memory in that case, if each user has their own session space.

Oracle object:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MyObject AS OBJECT 
(
     col1Data   VARCHAR2(10),
      MEMBER FUNCTION createData
          RETURN VARCHAR2 AS LANGUAGE JAVA
     NAME 'MyObject.createData() return java.lang.String'
);
```

Java code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "MyObject" AS

public class MyObject
{
    private String col1Data;

    public String createData ()
    {
         System.out.println ("col1: " + col1Data);  

    }
}
```

called by this oracle function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_myobject
    (col1 IN varchar2)
        RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    p_rc   varchar2(100);
    myObj  MyObject;

BEGIN

    myObj := new MyObject(col1);    

    p_rc := myObj.createData();   -- this line gets a 00932 error

    RETURN p_rc;

END;
```

Thanks again and sorry for the confusion on the first one.

Comment: static, members, instance, variables, functions but not a single line of code?

Comment: Please post your code as well.